# Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations, gradients

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a smooth bounded domain. Let $C_c^\infty(D)$ denote smooth and compactly supported functions on $D$.

Let $f \in [C_c^\infty(D)]^d$ be a smooth, compactly supported vector field on $D$,
such that
$$\int_D f \cdot \nabla \phi = 0 \quad \forall \phi \in C_c^\infty(D).$$

Question:
What can be said about $f$, besides that $\mathrm{div} \, f = 0$?

**Edit**: If $d = 3$ then $f$ could be $f = \mathrm{curl} \, w$ for any $w \in [C_c^\infty(D)]^3$, so not much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer is: **absolutely nothing**.

Take the reverse, *i.e.* let a locally integrable vector field $g$ satisfy the indentity
$$ \int\limits_Dg\cdot f\,dx=0\quad\forall\, f\in \bigl[C_c^{\infty}(D)\bigr]^d\colon\,{\rm div}\,f=0.$$
Such vector field $g$ is known to be potential. More precisely, there is a locally weakly
differentiable function $\phi$ such that $g=\nabla\phi\,$  *a.e.* in $D$. The reverse side of your question is *what else can be said about* $g$, *besides that* $g=\nabla\phi\,$? While the answer stays the same, **absolutely nothing**.

Comment: So, why nothing?